# django - Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

I'm using Django 1.4.1 with Active Python 2.7 on Win7. I have installed the MySQL module using `pypm install mysql-python`.

The database engine is `django.db.backends.mysql`.

**`import MySQLdb` works in the interactive shell.**

**`.\manage.py syncdb` created the tables with no problem.**

**However, when I open the site in the browser, I get `Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb`**:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://whatever/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  89.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py" in process_request
  10.         engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\cached_db.py" in <module>
  6. from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DBStore
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in <module>
  3. from django.db import IntegrityError, transaction, router
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py" in <module>
  40. backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py" in __getattr__
  34.         return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __getitem__
  92.         backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in load_backend
  24.         return import_module('.base', backend_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py" in <module>
  16.     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /
Exception Value: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

The settings for the sessions and messages apps are:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db"
MESSAGE_STORAGE = "django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie.CookieStorage"
```

How is this possible?

Comment: If you installed MySQLdb without restarting your web server it probably hasn't picked it up yet.

Comment: I have a script that checks for changes an restarts the server automatically. But never mind, I have found the issue and will post an answer.

Comment: Ah, now I realize I didn't read your comment properly. I'm using Apache with mod_wsgi, not the dev server that comes with Django. The MySQLdb module was installed days ago so that wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that MySQLdb was installed in my home directory `C:\Users\alexei\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\` which was not in Python's path. So I uninstalled it with `pypm uninstall mysql-python` and then reinstalled it **globally** using `pypm -g install mysql-python` (note the `-g` option).

The alternative is to add that path to the list `sys.path.append("...path...")` in `wsgi.py`

So, in case someone else is wondering, you can find out where MySQLdb (or any other module) is installed like so:

```
import MySQLdb
print MySQLdb.__file__
```

Make sure that that path is in Python's path list provided in Django's error message.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using and virtual environment. you must run

```
cd virtualEnvPath
pip install MySQL-Python
```

Don't forget positioning inside of your virtual env. /bin PATH, to use local pip.
REGARDS!

Comment: If you receive some similar to:

for package MySQL-Python
    sh: mysql_config: command not found

Then your are missing:

yum install python-devel mysql-devel ----> for CENTOS

Answer (score 1):

i also faced this issue then i  installed python mysql to my system

> pip install mysql-python

then its workes
**see this** -->
**working in my system   >> 
$ python manage.py syncdb;**
Creating tables ...
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
.............working

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to install MySQLdb from binary:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

Answer (score 1):

I configured djando w/ mysql the following way:

1) set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable in .bashrc and source it

2) change settings.py pointed by this env_var and local_settings.py (if any) like this (for mysql):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

3) install mysql dev libraries and header files, ensure that mysql is on PATH

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

4) install python package for mysql

```
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

5) test django's access to your mysql db:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

or

```
django-admin dbshell
```

6) sync django to mysql from dir with your django app

```
python manage.py syncdb
```