# How to resolve the following error in Django(1.4.2)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-settings

Am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
execute_manager(settings)
File "C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 382, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 232, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
cursor = connection.cursor()
File "C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 15, in complain
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check
settings documentation for more details.
```

following is my settings.py:-
    # Django settings for ecomstore project.

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

SITE_NAME = 'Modern Musician'
META_KEYWORDS = 'Music, instruments, sheet music, musician'
META_DESCRIPTION = 'Modern Musician is an online supplier of instruments, sheet music, and other accessories for musicians'

# CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath('.').decode('utf-8').replace('\\','/')
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).decode('utf-8'))

# Upon deployment, change to True
ENABLE_SSL = False

# Uncomment the following line after you have installed memcached on your local development machine
#CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'django.db.backends.mysql'           # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
DATABASE_NAME =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.mysql'),
             # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = 'root'             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = ''             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = ''             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

CACHE_TIMEOUT = 60 * 60


PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE = 1
PRODUCTS_PER_ROW = 4

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/my_account/'

SESSION_COOKIE_DAYS = 90
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24 * SESSION_COOKIE_DAYS 

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = False

# Absolute path to the directory that holds media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'static')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin_media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'io_)m-ijh_g#cz-k1p3=tzazb6v3d)h_u8b9cvex9yn%zbakmn'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.load_template_source',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'ecomstore.utils.context_processors.ecomstore',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.csrf.middleware.CsrfMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'djangodblog.DBLogMiddleware',
    'ecomstore.marketing.urlcanon.URLCanonicalizationMiddleware',
    'ecomstore.SSLMiddleware.SSLRedirect',
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
)

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.userprofile'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecomstore.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'ecomstore.catalog',
    'ecomstore.cart',
    'ecomstore.accounts',
    'ecomstore.search',
    'ecomstore.checkout',
    'ecomstore.utils',
    'ecomstore.stats',
    'djangodblog',
    'tagging',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.redirects',
    'ecomstore.billing',
    'ecomstore.caching',
)
# for use with URL Canonicalization Middleware:
# this is the canonical hostname to be used by your app (required)
CANON_URL_HOST = 'www.your-domain.com'
# these are the hostnames that will be redirected to the CANON_URL_HOSTNAME 
# (optional; if not provided, all non-matching will be redirected)
CANON_URLS_TO_REWRITE = ['your-domain.com', 'other-domain.com']

# Google Checkout API credentials
GOOGLE_CHECKOUT_MERCHANT_ID = ''
GOOGLE_CHECKOUT_MERCHANT_KEY = ''
GOOGLE_CHECKOUT_URL = 'https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/merchantCheckout/Merchant/' + GOOGLE_CHECKOUT_MERCHANT_ID

# Authorize.Net API Credentials
AUTHNET_POST_URL = 'test.authorize.net'
AUTHNET_POST_PATH = '/gateway/transact.dll'
AUTHNET_LOGIN = ''
AUTHNET_KEY = ''

# Google Analytics tracking ID
# should take the form of 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', where the X's are digits
ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID = ''

try:
    from settings_local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

I am using Django-1.4.2 and mysql.Please help resolve this error as tomorrow I have my project submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATABASES option is not configured in settings.py

Add this,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/path/to/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

More information is at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/

Comment: Yep, this works since 1.2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#databases

Comment: should i put 'read_default_file': '/path/to/my.cnf', as it is?

Comment: I put as it is then i get django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb @catavaran

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772687/django-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-module-named-mysqldb

Comment: Did that,installed mysql and created the ecomstore database,but when i run command 'python manage.py dbshell' it gives the error:                          'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Even added the mysql server bin folder to the environment variables