# Python running manage.py migrate wont work with MySQL db

Tags: python, mysql, django

Im working for a web application in **`Windows 10`** using **`Python 3`** and **`Django 1.9.7`**
I am trouble connecting the application to **`MySQL`** database.

I installed certain tool to established connection with **`MySQL`** using **`PYMySQL`** via **`cmd`**

**Output using `pip install PYMySQL`**

```
(bvc_env) C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\src>pip install pymysql
Collecting pymysql
  Using cached PyMySQL-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pymysql
Successfully installed pymysql-0.7.5
```

**Here is my Database option in `Settings.py`**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_app',
        'HOST': 'host_app',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
    }
}
```

Then after i saved and started to migrate using this code:

```
(bvc_env) C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\src>python manage.py migrate
```

**I got this ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 307, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

But this got my attention and i do not know how to fix these issue

`ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'` or `Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'`

> QUESTION UPDATE FEEDS

1. I tried installing other connector using `pip install mysql-python` but it doesn't seems to work for `Python 3`

> Got my solution by importing `pymysql` to your `manage.py file` here is the whole code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bvc.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772687/django-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-module-named-mysqldb

Comment: `mysql-python` won't work for me since it doesn't'support `Python 3`

Comment: `Failed building wheel for mysqlclient` it failed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/python-3-and-mysql , this should help. Upvote if it help